# Tomcat 7 java.lang.NullPointerException when wrong credential entered using Active Directory authentification

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, active-directory

I am trying to use Active Directory to authenticate users on my web
application. This is now working correctly if I use the right
credentials, but If I fail to input the correct credentials, I get the
following error [1] and no further attempts is allowed. I did not have
this issue when I was only using the UserDatabaseRealm.

**Edit:** After upgrading to Tomcat 8.0.15 as suggested by @kotacc, I am still getting an error (see [5] below) when entering the wrong credentials. **end of Edit**

My server.xml is in [2] and my web.xml in [3]
My configuration details are in [4].

Any idea of what is wrong? Could anyone point me to the right
documentation for this?

regards

Ben

[2] here is the relevant part from my server.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm. -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
        connectionURL="ldap://someServer.mycompany.com:389"
        connectionName="OneUser@mycompany.CORP"
        connectionPassword="aPassword"
        referrals="follow"
        userBase="ou=Users,OU=somServer,DC=mycompany,DC=CORP"
        userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
        userSubtree="true"
      />
     </Realm>
     </Realm>
```

[3] here is the relevant part from my web.xml:

```
 <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires
authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
        <description>Matches a few special pages.</description>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
        <!-- No auth-constraint means everybody has access! -->
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

  <security-role>
   <description>this is the standard user</description>
   <role-name>*</role-name>
 </security-role>
```

[4] This is on Tomcat 7.0.57 running on Windows 7 64 bit

```
> java -version java version "1.7.0_71" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 1.7.0_71-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

[1] here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1303)
org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1253)
org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1194)
org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1069)
org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:146)
org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:146)
org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:180)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:575)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[5] here is the error with Tomcat 8.0.15:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1286)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1236)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1177)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1052)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:157)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:157)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:180)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:111)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:576)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you try keeping `userPassword="userPassword"` in `JNDIRealm`?

Comment: Hi @kotacc, I added this with "userPassword" as my AD password but then I cannot login anymore, even with the correct credentials. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a defect in Tomcat 7.0.57. If you see the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_57/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/JNDIRealm.java) at line 1300, there is no null check. I've pasted the piece of code here and given my comment:

```
protected User getUser(DirContext context, String username,
                       String credentials, int curUserPattern)
    throws NamingException {
    ...
    if (userPatternFormatArray != null && curUserPattern >= 0) {
        user = getUserByPattern(context, username, credentials, attrIds, curUserPattern);
    } else {
        user = getUserBySearch(context, username, attrIds);
    }
    if (userPassword == null && credentials != null) { //Line 1300;No null check for 'user' object.
        return new User(user.getUserName(), user.getDN(), credentials,
                user.getRoles(), user.getUserRoleId());
    }
    return user;
}
```

Seems that lines from 1300 are added in Tomcat 7.0.57 version. I could also see that it is addressed in [trunk](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/JNDIRealm.java) but it is not released yet. I suggest you use either previous version (7.0.56) or Tomcat 8.

**[EDIT]**: It seems the defect is not fixed in all versions of Tomcat 8. As of now, the latest versions of Tomcat i.e 7.0.57 and 8.0.15 having this defect.

Comment: Hi @kotacc, first of all, thank you for looking into this and sorry for the slow response, it took me some time to upgrade to Tomcat 8.0.15. However, I still have the same crash in the same conditions see my edit of my original post and the logs in [5]. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @benvinsonneau, any reason that you have chosen 8.0.15? I thought it is fixed in all versions of Tomcat 8+. Seems it is not :( 
If you look at the source code, line 1300 is added in [8.0.15](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc8.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_8_0_15/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/JNDIRealm.java) and added the null check in [8.0.16](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc8.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_8_0_16/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/JNDIRealm.java) but not published yet. We ended up in same problem again. Sorry for suggesting wrong version, but you may try 8.0.14.

Comment: Hi @kotacc, Indeed my bad, I tried 8.0.14 and it works correctly now. Thank you for your help